# Django: loop a call to a template+view

Tags: django, templates, loops

I'm making a multi-page poll. I have a database that has a column called page and each page has a 4 questions. After the user answers all the questions on a page, she clicks "Next" and goes to the next page.

I can query the database to figure out the # of pages that I need to generate, but I'm not sure how to loop the template rendering process.

Here's my code:

The users enters:

```
def index(request):
latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.filter(page=1)
t = loader.get_template('index.html')
c = Context({
    'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
})
return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

...which generates this template:

```
    <ul>

<form action="/first/vote/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
    <li>{{ poll.question }}</li>
        {% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
            <input type="radio" name="choice{{ poll.id }}" id="{{poll.id}}choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
            <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice }}</label><br />
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>

</ul>
```

...the user's selection is then processed here:

```
def vote(request):
intra_page_key = request.POST['choice1']+','+request.POST['choice2']+','+request.POST['choice3']
request.session['p1'] = intra_page_key
return HttpResponse(request.session['p1'])
```

How do I repeat this sequence for page 2 of my poll?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [`FormWizard`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#urls.py
(r'^(?P<pollid>\d*)/$', 'app.views.index'),

#views.py
def index(request, pollid):    
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.filter(page=pollid)
    t = loader.get_template('index.html')
    c = Context({
        'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

also it would be good to read up on shortcut "get or 404"

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/?from=olddocs#a-shortcut-get-object-or-404